# Append TextField into Div JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, append, clone

I have a field with the id of "task_alignment" that has a value the user will be typing that needs to be added into the span below. The span has a value of 12 for the sake of example in the code below.. I can't seem to get this working.

```
<tr>
<td> Aligned To </td> 
<td class="task_table_item_last">
<input type='text' size='95' id='task_alignment' name='task_alignment' value='<?php echo $task_alignment; ?>'>
</td>
<td class="edit_taskicon"><img class="edit_icon_trigger" src="img/add.png"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td> 
<td class="aligncode_start">
    <span>12</span>

</td> 
</tr>
```

I have tried using the code below but it doesn't do anything:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $aligncode_newitem = $('<span id="aligncode_newitem">'#task_alignment '</span>'),
        $('.edit_icon_trigger').click(function() {
            $("#task_alignment").clone(aligncode_newitem);
        });
});​
</script>
```

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FakH7/ ?

Comment: @j08691 unexpected illegal token

Comment: @j08691 actually this works on the fiddle.. I want to keep adding new values into new spans.. sort of like the tag adding on stack

Comment: I'm not sure where you're seeing all these `unexpected illegal token` errors but it works fine.

Comment: Is this more what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FakH7/1/?

Comment: @j08691 Yes thats perfect! Works great on fiddle but I keep getting "unexpected token illegal" on the site

Comment: I'm guessing since it works in the fiddle that you have other code that may be causing your `unexpected token illegal` error. I'll post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.edit_icon_trigger').click(doit);
$('#task_alignment').keypress(function() {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        doit();
    }
});
function doit() {
    $("td.aligncode_start").html($("td.aligncode_start").html() + ' <span>' + $('#task_alignment').val() + '</span>');
    $('#task_alignment').val('').focus();
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FakH7/4/)**

Comment: @j0861 I need it to make a new span for each click... can you fix fiddle?

Comment: great! How about when a user presses enter..? :)

Comment: so a user can press the button or click enter

Answer (score 0):

To display the input value in span, you can do this

```
$('.edit_icon_trigger').on('click',function(){
  var value = $('input#task_alignment').val();
  $('.aligncode_start span').html(value);
});
```

you can test in this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/xBFKU/

Comment: I am getting an unexpected illegal token

Comment: That error might be related to something else, it should work with out any problem.

Comment: I need it to make a new span for each click... can you fix fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct for your requirement, you need to add "n" number to SPAN under the td class aligncode_start which is entered in the input text, right? If so, check the below code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/ecmascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".edit_icon_trigger").live("click", function () {
            $(".aligncode_start").append("<span>" + ($("#task_alignment").val()) + "</span>");
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Aligned To </td>
            <td class="task_table_item_last">
                <input type='text' size='95' id='task_alignment' name='task_alignment'>
            </td>
            <td class="edit_taskicon">
                <img class="edit_icon_trigger" src="img/add.png"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="aligncode_start">
                <span>12</span>

            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: `.live()` was deprecated in favor of `.on()` as of jQuery 1.7.

Comment: @j08691, thanks for the update. I'm a 1.4 user and just updating :)

Comment: @achuthakrishnan I am trying to add a new span for each click.. can you fix?

Comment: @greycode, The code which I have given does the same. append("<span>") does create a new span on each click. You mean to say you wanted new span with id everytime?